# Route @token confusion

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

Apologies if this has already been asked.

I am working on a project where I am looking to display locations of a business. This can be either by state, or by city (in a state).

I am trying to work with these two routes:

```
GET /@state
GET /@city-@state
```

@state works well, but when I try to navigate to a @city-@state page, I get errors because it is trying to load the @state page, and cannot find the required data.

Looking at base.php, I found that the preg_match_all is matching with \w, so it should be ignoring the hyphen(-), but for some reason isn't.

I need the URLs to be in this structure.

Can someone help me notice what I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you could detail how you declared those routes. Also which kind of URL you're requesting (if `@state` or `@city` contain hyphen, you could be in trouble).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think F3 allows you to use a dash to separate tokens in a url; hence why it's always matching the first token (@state).

The regex used to grab tokens is '/@(\w+)/', it wants a slash character to separate tokens.
I would suggest using /@state and /@city/@state.